# How to make custom routings

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-routing

I have a similar question and will try to code it by myself, but I don't know if it's possible. Can you give me a short hint on how to solve this.

I'm trying to get following solution:

```
www.mysite.ch/Home/Index

""/Home/About

""/Club/Manchester/{Controller}/{Action}/{Id}

""/Club/*anyClubName*/{Controller}/{Action}/{Id}
```

Can I solve this with routing options?

Comment: And a short hint - you aren't restricted to just using {Controller},{Action},{Id} as your placeholders in your routes - and they don't have to appear in that order in the URL. That should help you look in the right `Area`.

Comment: I think you should read this article - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/cc668201(v=vs.100).aspx